# Javascript syntax, using functionName vs. functionName()

Tags: javascript, object, methods

Considering This:

```
  var genericGreet = function() {
    return "Hello, my name is " + this.name;
  }

  var andrew = {
    name: "Andrew",
    greet: genericGreet
  }

  var ryan = {
    name: "Ryan",
    greet: genericGreet
  }

</script>
```

Why is it wrong to say `greet: genericGreet()` or `greet: genericGreet();`. The above is from an interactive quiz in a series of online learning for javascript at [treehouse.com](http://teamtreehouse.com/), and the interactive quiz is telling me that these would be incorrect, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

```
greet: genericGreet
```

will let `greet` also to point to the object pointed by `genericGreet`. So, `greet` is now an alias for the same function. But when you say

```
greet: genericGreet()
```

you are making `greet` point to the returned value of the `genericGreet` function. If you intend to call `greet` later on, then you should use

```
greet: genericGreet
```

only. Normally, people use Prototypal pattern to implement this

```
function PersonGreeter(personName) {
    this.name = personName; 
}

PersonGreeter.prototype.greet = function() {
    return "Hello, my name is " + this.name;
};

var andrew = new PersonGreeter("Andrew");
console.log(andrew.greet());
var ryan   = new PersonGreeter("Ryan");
console.log(ryan.greet());
```

**Output**

```
Hello, my name is Andrew
Hello, my name is Ryan
```